# How to use NOT in a Boolean var in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function where i want to inverse the value of `Bval`,
`Bval` is a boolean param.

```
function SomeMethod(Bval) {   
  $("#id_select_contact").attr("disabled", Bval); // Habilitar.
  $('#id_select_contact option').eq(0).prop('selected', NOT Bval); //Seleccionar
  return;
}
```

i know that using `NOT` is wrong.
So any ideas ?

Comment: try ! instead of 'NOT'

Comment: are you looking for the '!' character? !Bval

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29. These kind of problems are best solve by reading a [JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SomeMethod(Bval) {
  $("#id_select_contact").attr("disabled", Bval); // Habilitar.
  $('#id_select_contact option').eq(0).prop('selected', !Bval); //Seleccionar
  return;
}
```

This is the w3 Schools guide for Logical operators. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: There's probably a [more reliable](http://www.w3fools.com/) reference you can link to than w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

The logical negation operator in javascript is `!`

so you have: !true === false and !false === true

Comment: This Answer is useful. Thanks ! (StackOverflow Said: Vote Up requires 15 reputation).

Answer (score 0):

see [JavaScript Expressions and Operators](http://lib.ru/JAVA/javascr/expr.html) for reference:

```
var myVal = true;
var myInvertedValue = !myVal;
```

the `!`-Operator is negation.

Comment: This Answer is useful. Thanks ! (StackOverflow Said: Vote Up requires 15 reputation).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the not operator is a bang ! and isn't literal NOT.  Use the exclamation point to not things.

Comment: This Answer is useful. Thanks ! (StackOverflow Said: Vote Up requires 15 reputation).

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would just be  `!Bval`

Answer (score 0):

The Boolean object is used to convert a non-Boolean value to a Boolean value (true or false).

Boolean Object Properties

**constructor**:    Returns the function that created the Boolean object's prototype
; **prototype**:    Allows you to add properties and methods to a Boolean object

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to create a boolean object, then display it's constructor</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var myvar=new Boolean(1);
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=! 1;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function SomeMethod(Bval) {   
$("#id_select_contact").attr("disabled", Bval);
Bval = (Bval==true)?false:true;  //or  try, Bval =!Bval;
$('#id_select_contact option').eq(0).prop('selected',Bval); 
return;
```

}

Comment: This Answer is useful. Thanks ! (StackOverflow Said: Vote Up requires 15 reputation).

Comment: Your most welcome @Nuevo Laredo, 
Happy to help you.... Your satisfaction is my Vote...